# Quotation marks showing up as literals in linked url

Tags: html

I have a footer section that contains a list of links. For some reason, the linked urls are accepting the quotation marks as part of the link within my href attribute:

```
<footer>
<br><a href=“stylesandformatting.html” target=“_blank”>Styles and Formatting</a>
<br><a href=“morestylesandformatting.html” target=“_blank”>More Styles and Formatting</a>
<br><a href=“layouts.html” target=“_blank”>Layouts</a>
<br><a href=“tableslistsandiframes.html” target=“_blank”>Tables Lists and iFrames</a>
<br><a href=“css.html” target=“_blank”>CSS Syntax, Selectors and Combinators</a>
<br><a href=“responsivedesign.html” target=“_blank”>Responsive Design</a>
<br><a href=“imagegallery.html” target=“_blank”>Image Gallery</a>
</footer>
```

When I go to click on a link, here's the resulting URL: http://mrwilliams.net/web_design/kgiannamore/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C5%93stylesandformatting.html%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9D

When I remove the quotation marks from the code, the links work perfectly normal:

```
<br><a href=stylesandformatting.html target=_blank>Styles and Formatting</a>
  <br><a href=morestylesandformatting.html target=_blank>More Styles and Formatting</a>
  <br><a href=layouts.html target=_blank>Layouts</a>
  <br><a href=tableslistsandiframes.html target=_blank>Tables Lists and iFrames</a>
  <br><a href=css.html target=_blank>CSS Syntax, Selectors and Combinators</a>
  <br><a href=responsivedesign.html target=_blank>Responsive Design</a>
  <br><a href=imagegallery.html target=_blank>Image Gallery</a>
```

Can someone tell me what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Those appear to be curly or "smart" quotation marks, not regular ol' straight quotation marks. Your editor might be automatically turning quotation marks into "smart" quotes, which is great for text but bad for markup.

[Here's an article](http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html) that might help you resolve the issue, or at least understand it better.

Comment: There are other links on the page with the same quotation marks that do work

Comment: can you post a link to the page that has some working and some not working?

Comment: I'm not seeing any examples of this behavior on that page; it's possible that this behavior varies by browser? I'm not sure. But I am pretty certain it's some kind of text encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This is working fine for me.

```
<footer>
<br><a href="stylesandformatting.html" target="_blank">Styles and Formatting</a>
<br><a href="morestylesandformatting.html" target="_blank">More Styles and Formatting</a>
<br><a href="layouts.html" target="_blank">Layouts</a>
<br><a href="tableslistsandiframes.html" target="_blank">Tables Lists and iFrames</a>
<br><a href="css.html" target="_blank">CSS Syntax, Selectors and Combinators</a>
<br><a href="responsivedesign.html" target="_blank">Responsive Design</a>
<br><a href="imagegallery.html" target="_blank">Image Gallery</a>
</footer>
```

Thanks.